# how to split a string and store in array in pl/sql

Tags: arrays, plsql, split

i need to split a string and store in array, i have tried the following pl/sql code,

```
SELECT y.* 
FROM (
    select trim(regexp_substr(str,'[^$]+', 1, level)) as str1
    from ( 
       SELECT 'key1:string$key2:bring$key3:T-ring$' as Str 
       FROM dual 
    )
    connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^$]+', 1, level) is not null
) x
CROSS APPLY(
    select trim(regexp_substr(str1,'[^:]+', 1, 1)) as key,
           trim(regexp_substr(str1,'[^:]+', 1, 2)) as value
    from dual
) y
```

colon(:) is used for key value sepration and dollor($) is used for separation.

output:

[image]

it worked for me, it is printing the output, but i need to store the output in a variable/array, and i am not getting **how to store the returned value into an array(key-value pair) for validation purpose**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option.

Create types to hold data:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row as object (key varchar2(10), value varchar2(10));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab is table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Procedure which a) stores data into a collection, b) displays the result:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_tab t_tab;
  3    l_str varchar2(100) := 'key1:string$key2:bring$key3:T-ring';
  4  begin
  5    with temp as
  6      (select regexp_substr(l_str, '[^$]+', 1, level) val
  7       from dual
  8       connect by level <= regexp_count(l_str, '\$') + 1
  9      )
 10    select t_row(substr(val, 1, instr(val, ':') - 1),
 11                 substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1)
 12                )
 13    bulk collect into l_tab
 14    from temp;
 15
 16    for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
 17      dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i).key ||' - '|| l_tab(i).value);
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /
key1 - string
key2 - bring
key3 - T-ring

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to use locally-defined types (the ones that exist only in your PL/SQL procedure), then

```
SQL> declare
  2    type  t_row is record (key varchar2(10), value varchar2(10));
  3    type  t_tab is table of t_row;
  4    l_tab t_tab;
  5    l_str varchar2(100) := 'key1:string$key2:bring$key3:T-ring';
  6  begin
  7    with temp as
  8      (select regexp_substr(l_str, '[^$]+', 1, level) val
  9       from dual
 10       connect by level <= regexp_count(l_str, '\$') + 1
 11      )
 12    select substr(val, 1, instr(val, ':') - 1),
 13                 substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1)
 14    bulk collect into l_tab
 15    from temp;
 16
 17    for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
 18      dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i).key ||' - '|| l_tab(i).value);
 19    end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
key1 - string
key2 - bring
key3 - T-ring

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: but i don't wanted to create a new table, i wanted to store into an array,

Comment: Ummm ... where exactly do you see a new table?

Comment: create or replace type t_tab is table of t_row; in this line.. i don't wanted to create separate things, i need to code in one procedure only. how can i add those create or replace line into my procedure?

Comment: That's not a table, but a type. Have a look at edited answer.

Comment: can you please explain why EXISTS isn't working on that l_tab variable? i need to check whether key exists in l_tab or not. if it exists then assign that particular value to a variable... I really appreciate any help you can provide.